# Multiples features inside a feature

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have defined a Store with `Angular` and `NgRx` 13. I have a `SharedModule` where I define component such as selectors, etc. Each selector content is loaded in the `store`, so that I can avoid the repeat of an API call.

[image]

This is defined in this way:

*shared.module.ts*

```js
/**...*/
 StoreModule.forFeature(clientsFeature),
 StoreModule.forFeature(prioritiesFeature),
/**...*/
```

*clients.feature.ts*

```js
import { createFeature, createSelector, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ClientDTO } from '@shared/model/client.models';

import * as ClientsActions from './clients.actions';

export const initialState: ClientDTO[] = [];

export const clientsFeature = createFeature({
  name: 'clients',
  reducer: createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(ClientsActions.getClientListSuccess, (state, { clients }): ClientDTO[] => clients)
  ),
});

export const selectClientList = createSelector(clientsFeature.selectClientsState, clients => clients);
```

Priorities feature is similar.

What I'm trying to do is avoiding to declare each feature and use a 'shared' feature that contains all the subfeatures. To do this, I create:

*index.ts*

```js
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ClientDTO } from '@shared/model/client.models';
import { Priority } from '@shared/model/priorities.models';
import { clientsFeature } from './clients/clients.reducer';
import { prioritiesFeature } from './priorities/priorities.reducer';

export const sharedFeatureKey = 'shared';

export interface SharedState {
  clients: ClientDTO[] | null;
  priorities: Priority[] | null;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<SharedState> = {
  clients: clientsFeature.reducer,
  priorities: prioritiesFeature.reducer,
};
```

And my *shared.module* :

```js
    StoreModule.forFeature(fromShared.sharedFeatureKey, fromShared.reducers),
```

[image]

All ok.

**PROBLEM**

Doing this I cannot access to the content of the list. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I don't know what. I get this warning:

> ngrx-store.mjs:724 @ngrx/store: The feature name "clients" does not exist in the state, therefore createFeatureSelector cannot access it.  Be sure it is imported in a loaded module using StoreModule.forRoot('clients', ...) or StoreModule.forFeature('clients', ...).  If the default state is intended to be undefined, as is the case with router state, this development-only warning message can be ignored.

And another similar with priorities. I'm pretty sure that the problem are in the selectors, but after trying for hours, I cannot found a solution.

The undefineds are the log of the content of the selector:

```js
    this.store
      .select(selectPrioritiesList)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(priorities => {
        console.log('priorities -->', priorities);
      });
```

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to fix selectors
Look at #5 in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72884560/13824324

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the selectors.
Because you added an extra "shared" layer, the selectors need to be updated.

Currently, the `createFeature` isn't configurable and uses the top level state to select sub-states. This means you can't use the provided selectors from `createFeature`, but you'll have to write the selectors manually.